# External Program Configuration zend studio

Tags: zend-studio

In Eclispe, I am able to go to Run > External Tools > External Tools Configuration and see an option called "Program" on the left. From there I can add a configuration that runs an external perl script, in this case one that scps the file I'm working on up to a remote server.

Is it possible to do this in Zend Studio? I can't see the "Program" option in the Configuration panel - the left pane is just blank. Hoping there's a straightforward answer for this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the matter of configuration filtering. Get into filtering pull-down menu (see screenshot) and uncheck "Filter configuration types" option.

[image: filtering options screenshot]